# How to pass complex vars for tpl file in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a tpl file. So i can give my role,  access to multiple k8s cluster. But i'm getting a tuple error.

How should we pass vars to tpl file when it has some interpolation?
Please also let me know what does this error mean and where i'm wrong.

Terraform version: 0.12.28

locals.tf

```
 federated = [
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
  ]

federatedList1 = [for oidc in local.federated : "arn:aws:iam::11111111111:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/${oidc}"]
  federatedList2 = join("", [for oidc in local.federated : "\"oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/${oidc}:sub:\", \"system:serviceaccount:%s:%s\""])
```

eks_assume_policy.json.tpl

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "${federatedList1}"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "${federatedList2}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

IAM role

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "route53_role" {
  name = "xxxxx"
  assume_role_policy = format(templatefile("./eks_assume_policy.json.tpl", {
    federatedList1 = [for oidc in local.federated : "arn:aws:iam::1111111111:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/${oidc}"]
    federatedList2 = join("", [for oidc in local.federated : "\"oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/${oidc}:sub:\", \"system:serviceaccount:%s:%s\""])
  }), "namespace", local.name)

  tags = {
    terraform = "true"
    owner     = "test"
  }
}
```

Error: Error in function call

```
 on main.tf line 49, in resource "aws_iam_role" "route_53_role":
  49:   assume_role_policy = format(templatefile("./eks_assume_policy.json.tpl", {
  50:
  51:
  52:
    |----------------
    | local.federated is tuple with 2 elements

Call to function "templatefile" failed: ./eks_assume_policy.json.tpl:7,25-39:
Invalid template interpolation value; Cannot include the given value in a
string template: string required..
```

Update1:

I'm trying eks_assume_policy.json.tpl to access both cluster

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": [
          "arn:aws:iam::111111111:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "arn:aws:iam::111111111:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/yyyyyyyyyyy"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxxxxxxxxxx:sub": "system:serviceaccount:%s:%s",
          "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/yyyyyyyyy:sub": "system:serviceaccount:%s:%s"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'm guessing that it doesn't like trying to interpolate `federatedList1` into the `eks_assume_policy.json.tpl` file - as it says, a string is required, but you are passing a list.

Answer (score 2):

Often, a pattern used to overcome this issue is through [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html). In this case the template file would be:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": ${jsonencode(federatedList1)}
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": 
          ${jsonencode(federatedList2)}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The `federatedList1` should be correct now.  I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with `federatedList2`, thus the modifications to `federatedList2` may need more tinkering.

Comment: Not sure either about intention of `federatedList2`, but it is a String in TF passed to a JSON expecting a Map, so the `jsonencode` function would not fix the additional JSON syntax issue there.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Same, as I wrote handling `federatedList2` probably will need more changes, depending on the intended outcome.

Comment: Sure, but at the moment you have a JSON syntax error unless you remove the `{}` which the asker added that incorrectly denote a Map value when he/she and you are actually using a String.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I see. Thanks. I removed the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

[The `templatefile` documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) includes a section specifically about this situation, titled [Generating JSON or YAML from a template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html#generating-json-or-yaml-from-a-template), which starts by saying:

> If the string you want to generate will be in JSON or YAML syntax, it's often tricky and tedious to write a template that will generate valid JSON or YAML that will be interpreted correctly when using lots of individual interpolation sequences and directives.
>
> Instead, you can write a template that consists only of a single interpolated call to either `jsonencode` or `yamlencode`, specifying the value to encode using normal Terraform expression syntax.

The docs then go on to give some simple examples of a template whose entire content is a call to `jsonencode` or `yamldecode`, but since you gave a specific template as an example here I can show the result of converting your template to the form that the documentation suggests:

```
${jsonencode({
  Version = "2012-10-17"
  Statement = [
    {
      Effect = "Allow"
      Principal = {
        Federated = federatedList1
      }
      Action = "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
      Condition = {
        StringEquals = federatedList2
      }
    },
  ]
})}
```

Notice that in this example the *entire template* is a single [interpolation sequence](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/strings.html#interpolation) `${ ... }`, and its result will be the JSON equivalent of the Terraform expression given as an argument to `jsonencode`. That means you can use all of the normal [Terraform language expression features](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/), including direct references to values you passed in from the main configuration, and Terraform will automatically convert the result to suitable JSON syntax.

In this case, because `federatedList1` and `federatedList2` are both tuples resulting from your `for` expressions, the result would be JSON arrays per the type mapping table shown in [the `jsonencode` function's documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html).